# What does my .contains() method evaluate to?

Tags: java, split

Here is my code. This is a method from a class that is passed a string as a parameter in this case "moss 25". My question is why does the part of the method that is commented out not work i.e. not split, but the part that is not commented out splits perfectly fine. I'm assuming it is because my if statement is not evaluated to true.

What am I missing?

class StringFormatter
{

```
public void lineRead(String br)
{


   /* String reader = br;
    String delimiters = "\\s+";
    if(reader.contains(delimiters))
        {
            String[] parts = reader.split(delimiters);
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];

            System.out.println(part1);
            System.out.println(part2);


        }
    else
     System.out.println(reader);
    */



     String reader = br;
     String delimiters = "\\s+";
     String[] parts = reader.split(delimiters);
     String part1 = parts[0];
     String part2 = parts[1];

     System.out.println(part1);
     System.out.println(part2);

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) does not use regular expressions.

Since your string doesn't contain a `\` followed by a `s` followed by a `+`, it returns false. Then, since it returned false, your code doesn't try to split the string.

Comment: Alright how to check for white space characters in a string then? I was thinking that \\s meant whitespace.

Comment: Andd Solved. I have been trying to figure this out for awhile and I find the answer right after asking. Thanks